# How to use GET method to open url in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')
w.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

This is my code and my browser is opening but my last line is not executing and not been able to open urls

Comment: check your chromedriver name, you have mentioned `chrome.exe` it may be `chromedriver.exe`